# issue with the float property

Tags: html, css

I have a small issue with my div-s as you can see

```
<div class="bigbig">

<div class="small">

</div>
<div class="big">

</div>
<div class="small">

</div>

</div>

.bigbig {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid red;
}

.small {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: calc(100% /2);
  float: left;
  border: solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big{
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
  border: solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jump3r/776rp8ne

How can I float the third div under the first div.

Thanks

Comment: You can float the the big div to the right.

Comment: @cwanjt thats not the point. I want to float the third under the first one

Comment: Although it might not sound logical, floating the `big` div to the right is exactly what you need to do, I've explained why in my answer below (it was the the first answer you got, you'll see it at the top if you order by oldest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working as it should, because it will keep floating each new div to the left, and if something is blocking it, it will go to a new line.

What you need to do is float the `.big` div to the right. That takes it out of the flow for the left-floating divs and it will line up nicely to the left where you want it:

```
.big{
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 100%;
  float:right;
  border: solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**See it in a working snippet:**

```css
.bigbig {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid red;
}

.small {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: calc(100% /2);
  float: left;
  border: solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.big{
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 100%;
  float:right;
  border: solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigbig">

<div class="small">
</div>
<div class="big">
</div>

<div class="small">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I've copied your code from your fiddle in the code snippet in my answer, and just changed the float for `.big`. Here is your fiddle updated with just that 1 line changed: https://jsfiddle.net/776rp8ne/3/  It works the same as the snippet above - I just put it directly in my answer as its easier to see.

Comment: A 3-column layout is a different issue altogether! The only way to get that layout to work for 3 columns using `float` alone is to group the 3 columns into 3 separate "column" divs first, and position those. You would also need to adjust the css for the `big` and `small` divs accordingly. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/776rp8ne/5/

Comment: ok, but there will be more div-s under these and there will be more big div-s. I wonder how can I fix this without putting them in separate div-s

Comment: If you can't organise the divs into column divs then the only way to do it is using javascript or jQuery. You are probably looking for a masonry layout, and there are various jQuery plugins available to do this such as masonry.js or bricks.js. But that goes way beyond what your original question, so I suggest you close this question (as it has technically been answered), take a look at the masonry layout & plugins and when you know more about what you'd like, ask new question with the `jquery` `masonry` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Float the `div` with the class `big` right. Like so...

```
<div class="bigbig">

<div class="small">

</div>
<div class="big" style="float:right;">

</div>
<div class="small">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just change the `.big` to the right

Using `float:left;` on the `.big` will take the 2nd `.small` position, even if there's no proper space

```
   .big{
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: 100%;
  float:right;
  border: solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, but how can I then place two another div-s right from the big one (one under the other), if I set the big one to float right.

Comment: You want another two .small inside the .big? or under it, outside of the .bigbig?